# How can I clone a database with Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I want to duplicate a database using Mongoid. I've tried

```
Mongoid.default_session.command(copydb: 1,fromdb: "source", todb: "destination")
```

But this gives me an error as I'm not currently in the admin database. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be inside the admin database to do this. So you can do:

```
  Mongoid.default_session.with(database: :admin) do |admin|
    admin.command(copydb: 1, fromdb: "source", todb: "destination")
  end
```